# Unity не открывает скрипт в Visual Studio 2017

Tags: unity3d, unity3d-editor

Работаю себе спокойно на одном компьютере, делаю игру. Потом перехожу на другую машину, но тут происходит ужасное! При попытке открыть скрипт unity "говори мне, что мой звонок очень важен для нас и чтобы я продолжал ждать". Вообщем, не открывается. Обновил компонент в ide, установил .exe файл в качестве редактора, создал пустой проект. Но ничего не помогает. Открытие файла в отдельности не позволяет комфортно работать с программной частью движка, ибо vs не распознаёт библиотеки unity. После проверки на других версиях понял, что проблема именно в unity 2019 alpha.

Answer (score 0):

Юнити для сцен использует файлы с расширением, которое по умолчанию прописано в `.gitignore`. Если я не ошибаюсь, это расширение `obj`. В общем, исправь gitignore и запушь все необходимые для проекта файлы с первого комьютера.